# Can Kendo UI multiselect integrate with kendo validator

Tags: angularjs, validation, kendo-ui, message

In this part of code i try to integrate Kendo validator with kendo multiselect.

```
 var validator = $("#form" + $scope.field).kendoValidator({
      messages: {
          required: function () {
              if (typeof $scope.validationMessage == 'undefined')
                  return 'This field is required';
              return $scope.validationMessage
           ,
       }
}).data("kendoValidator")



$scope.MultiSelectOptions = {
     placeholder: $scope.placeholder,
     dataTextField: 'model',
     dataValueField: 'model',
     dataSource: $scope.currentEntityDataSource,
 };
```

And my html

```
    <select kendo-multi-select
                ng-class="$parent.inputClass()"
                id="{{$parent.field}}"
                ng-model="$parent.$parent.config.selectedData[field]"
                k-options="MultiSelectOptions"></select>
```

This seems fine for me, but the validation message never show up. 
I have try the same code with  kendo-date-time and works!

Comment: What does $scope.validationMessage contain? Could it be blank or null?

Comment: no. i try the same code with another kendo widget and works